# Update data of one column in mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a column in my table as `photourl` and it has values as photo names for ex: 
 
`DSCF9055, DSCF9056, DSCF9057` and so on...

How can I update full column to get following output: 
`DSCF9055.JPG
DSCF9056.JPG
DSCF9057.JPG
.
.
.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table set column = CONCAT(column, '.JPG');
```

But it seems too easy to be what you really need...